# Why is NSArray empty at the time when UITableView Cell is selected?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have list of file with some name of friends. I am trying to understand UITableViewNavigation . I load the list from a file but when I select a cell the Data Array at that point seems empty and I can not work out why.
At this method I get this error

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        FriendsNameViewController *newView =[[FriendsNameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FriendsNameViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
        //Crashes here
        NSString *temp = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@",temp);
        [[newView labelx] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@" ,temp]];
    }
```

> 2011-10-03 14:43:08.411 navman2[69691:b303] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray
>   objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array'

---

**Interface**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSArray *dataArray;
}

@property(retain,nonatomic) NSArray *dataArray;

@end
```

**and then implementaion here**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "FriendsNameViewController.h"

@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize dataArray;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfriendsList" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSStringEncoding encoding;
    NSError* error;
    NSString* fh = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
    dataArray = [NSArray alloc];
    dataArray = [fh componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [dataArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}



#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    FriendsNameViewController *newView =[[FriendsNameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FriendsNameViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
    //Crashes here
    NSString *temp = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",temp);
    [[newView labelx] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@" ,temp]];
}

@end
```

Comment: changing code in `viewDidunload` to `self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray alloc];`
   `self.dataArray = [fh componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];` fixes it but I do not get the difference.I know it has something to do with  Autorelease but what difference does self make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have verified that the array is correct prior to selecting, then the first thing I would try is to rearrange your code a little bit:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        FriendsNameViewController *newView =[[FriendsNameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FriendsNameViewController" bundle:nil];       
        NSString *temp = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@",temp);
        [[newView labelx] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@" ,temp]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Could it be due to array getting autoreleased?UIViewTable populates fine but then array goes empty.Will try your code.What do you think may be my initialization of array is not correct what do you think.

Comment: Yeah, when you assign the array in your viewDidLoad you might want to use self.dataArray. If I remember correctly this will call retain on the property.